# Uncaught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON. I can't send the response to ajax

Tags: javascript

This is my first time working with ajax and js. I'm trying to display movie theater models on the page, but when transmitting a response, I get an error.
Tried to pass the response via JsonResponse.But it gave out an error that I could not understand.

views.py

```
class CinemasListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CinemaSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Cinema.objects.filter(city=CityLocation.objects.get(pk=self.request.GET.get('city_id'))).all()
        print(list(queryset))
        
        return queryset
```

serializers.py

```
class CinemaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = models.Cinema
        fields = '__all__'
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $("[id^='cinema']").click((event) => {
        var cityID = event.target.attributes['data-city-id'].value;

        $.ajax({
            url: `http://localhost:8000/myapp/get_theatre_by_city_id?city_id=${cityID}`,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "x-csrf-token": $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
                contentType: 'application/json',
            },
            
            success: (response) => {
                parsed = JSON.parse(response.cinemas);
                
                $("#result").html('');
                parsed.forEach(cinema=> {
                    var cinemaName = cinema.fields.all;

                    $("#result").append(`
                        <div style="float: left;">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-top-fluid"
                                        src="/media/${cinema.fields.image}"
                                        alt="">
                                </a>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title">
                                        <a href="/myapp/${cinema.fields.url}">${cinema.fields.cinema}</a>
                                    </h4>
                                    <h5>${cinema.fields.city}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">${cinema.fields.address}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    `);
                });
            },
            error: () => {
                alert("Ошибочка")
            }
        })
```

The JSON:

> (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}] 0 :  {id: 1, city: 'Караганда', cinema: 'cinema1', address: 'edsfsdfsdfds', image: 'http://localhost:8000/media/media/p223x267_jrepkmS.png', …} 1 :  {id: 3, city: 'Караганда', cinema: 'sfdgsdfsdf', address: 'fsdfsdfsd', image: 'http://localhost:8000/media/media/p223x267_1_fJflMbV.png', …} 2 :  {id: 4, city: 'Караганда', cinema: 'fgdsgsrgsrg', address: 'srgsrgrsgsrgsrgsr', image: 'http://localhost:8000/media/media/p223x267_ft2l6Dl.png', …} length :  3 [[Prototype]] : Array(0)

Comment: Please show the JSON response. Judging from the title of your question, it is malformed.

Comment: ```JsonResponse({"models_to_return": queryset}, safe=False)```

Comment: That's not what I meant. Show the actual JSON as returned by the HTTP request, e.g. using `curl`

Comment: ```path('get_theatre_by_city_id', views.CinemasListView.as_view(), name='get_theatre_by_city_id')```

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost:8000/myapp/get_theatre_by_city_id?city_id=1

Comment: `console.log(response)` - add that to your `success: function(response)`, and tell us what it's logging to the console. As @Gereon mentioned, it might be that your JSON is malformed, which would lead to `JSON.parse(response)` throwing an error.

Comment: Still not what I was talking about. Please edit your question with the output of `curl http://localhost:8000/myapp/get_theatre_by_city_id?city_id=1`. You can also try to check the validity of the output by running `curl http://localhost:8000/myapp/get_theatre_by_city_id?city_id=1 | jq`

Comment: ```(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
{id: 1, city: 'Караганда', cinema: 'cinema1', address: 'edsfsdfsdfds', image: 'http://localhost:8000/media/media/p223x267_jrepkmS.png', …}
1
: 
{id: 3, city: 'Караганда', cinema: 'sfdgsdfsdf', address: 'fsdfsdfsd', image: 'http://localhost:8000/media/media/p223x267_1_fJflMbV.png', …}
2
: 
{id: 4, city: 'Караганда', cinema: 'fgdsgsrgsrg', address: 'srgsrgrsgsrgsrgsr', image: 'http://localhost:8000/media/media/p223x267_ft2l6Dl.png', …}
length
: 
3
[[Prototype]]```
: 
Array(0)

Comment: That output doesn't appear to be JSON but a JavaScript Array.

Comment: @Egor The JavaScript Object doesn't have the  `fields` property. Hence try once without `fields` property. i.e `var cinemaName = cinema.all;` , `cinema.image`

Answer (score 0):

Your line of

```
parsed = JSON.parse(response.cinemas)
```

attempts to `parse` a textual value into a JSON, but the parameter you pass - `response.cinemas` assumes that your `response` is already an object and has a `.cinemas` member, which your JSON appears not to have. So, you will need to find out exactly what your `response` is. If it's an object already, then you do not need to `parse` it and you can already use it as it is. In that case check whether it has a `cinemas` key. Your JSON does not appear to have a `cinemas` key, maybe `response` is the cinemas, at least this looks plausible looking at your data. Otherwise, if you received something else, i.e. a text instead of an object, then `parse` it via `JSON.parse(response)` and you can refer any member of your object to the result of the parsing.